# I need help connecting to access using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

My program doesn't use the connection string that i want it to. Instead it finds the access file in this folder and displays the error:

> Could not find file 'C:\Users\user\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2008\Projects\Patientt\Patientt\bin\Debug\db_hospital.accdb'.

here is my code

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

        Provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.oleDB.12.0;data source=" '& System.Environment.CurrentDirectory.ToString() & "\namu.mdb"
        datafile = "\DemsV.accdb"

        connString = Provider & datafile
        Try
            myConnection.ConnectionString = connString
            myConnection.Open()

            Dim str As String
            str = "insert into Member([MemberID],[Name],[Surname],[Date of Birth],[Contacts],[Gender],) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)"
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, myConnection)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("MemberID", CType(txtmemberid.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Name", CType(txtname.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Surname", CType(txtsurname.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Date of Birth ", CType(DateTimePicker1.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Contacts", CType(txtcontacts.Text, String)))
            cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Gender", CType(comGender.Text, String)))


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)

        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Google: _How to debug in VB.Net?_. It can help you throughout your programming career (not being sarcastic).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something along the lines of this?

```
  Try
        Dim dbProvider As String
        Dim dbSource As String

        mainDBconnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection

        dbProvider = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="
        dbSource = ' Path to your database

        mainDBconnection.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource
        mainDBconnection.Open()

    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

It's basically done like this.

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class Form1



    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        ' Requires: Imports System.Data.OleDb

        ' ensures the connection is closed and disposed
        Using connection As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
            "Data Source=""C:\your_path_here\InsertInto.mdb"";" & _
            "Persist Security Info=False")
            ' open connection
            connection.Open()

            ' Create command
            Dim insertCommand As New OleDbCommand( _
                "INSERT INTO Table1([inputOne] , [inputTwo] , [inputThree]) " & _
                "VALUES (@inputOne, @inputTwo, @inputThree);", _
                connection)
            ' Add the parameters with value
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputOne", TextBox1.Text)
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputTwo", TextBox2.Text)
            insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inputThree", TextBox3.Text)
            ' you should always use parameterized queries to avoid SQL Injection
            ' execute the command
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MessageBox.Show("Insert is done!!")

        End Using

    End Sub
End Class
```

Can you adapt that to your specific needs?